# What is the direct connection between LWE and GapSVP?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto

**Learning with Errors Problem (LWE)**: Given a polynomial number of random noisy linear equations $b_i$ in the form of pairs

$$
 (a_i, \quad b_i = \langle s, a_i \rangle + e_i)
$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}^n_q$ are uniformly random, $e_i$ is sampled from some noise distribution such that $e_i \ll q$, and  $\langle s, a_i \rangle$ denotes the inner product of $s$ and $a_i$, find the secret vector $s \in \mathbb{Z}^n_q$.

This problem is supposed to rely on the hardness of GapSVP. In Regev's paper, he showed a complicated reduction from GapSVP. Is there a way to see the immediate connection between the two problems? What are $a_i$, $b_i$ and $\langle s, a_i \rangle$ with regards to a lattice?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try reading e.g. Section 3 of https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/602.pdf outlining the related lattice and the gap between $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that really helped. You should post it as the actual answer!

Answer (score 3):

Taking $n$ LWE samples, the associated vector $\mathbf{b} = (b_1, \dots, b_n)$ can be written as $A\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{e}$ with $A^T = (\mathbf{a}_1 | \dots | \mathbf{a}_n)$ and $\mathbf{e} = (e_1, \dots, e_n)$ a small noise vector. The vector $A\mathbf{s}$ could be interpreted as a lattice point in the lattice $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{a}_1, \dots, \mathbf{a}_n)$, with unknown coefficients defined by the secret vector $\mathbf{s}$, and $\mathbf{e}$ is small so $\mathbf{b}$ is pretty close to this lattice point. This corresponds to a CVP/BDD-style problem, where you want to find the closest lattice vector to $\mathbf{b}$ in this lattice.

Finally, Kannan's embedding technique shows how to translate CVP instances to (Gap-)SVP instances. Quoting [Hanrot, Pujol, and Stehle](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.stehle/downloads/SVPCVP.pdf), at the end of Section 4:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is also how Regev reduces GapSVP to LWE, but it's probably the most intuitive way to see how CVP-style problems and SVP-style problems are usually related.

Answer (score 2):

> SVP and GapSVP

For uniformly distributed $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}^n_q$ we are tasked with finding $s \in \mathbb{Z}^n_q$.  This can be seen as the search form SVP, but by stating that the hardness derives from GapSVP the claim then becomes a decision form.  GapSVP is also shown to reduce to GapCVP, and SVP is not harder than CVP ([source](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~daniele/papers/GMSS.pdf)).  It has also been shown that SVP reduces to GapSVP ([source](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04138))

> Intuitive Sense

For the noisy linear $b_i$ w.r.t. $(a_i, \quad b_i = \langle s, a_i \rangle + e_i)$ can you show that $s$ is the shortest non-zero vector when you only know $(a_i, b_i)$ and $a$ is uniformly random?  To put it another way, I task you with finding the shortest non-zero vector $s$, but to each vector I add slight noise using a Guassian distribution.  You will not be able to determine if $s$ is indeed this short vector, since the noise used can lead to an $s$ modulo an arbitrary number of decimal places.

> LWE and GapSVP

The immediate connection between LWE and GapSVP is that in both you are tasked with finding the shortest non-zero vector in the presence of a uniformly distributed noise.  In both, LWE and GapSVP have the difficulty of finding the secret $s$ which is as hard as distinguishing pairs such that the shortest non-zero vector has at most length $d$ from the pairs.  If I can't find the shortest non-zero vector, how can I decide if a pair of which the shortest vector is an element is at most length $d$?  Since I can't find $s$, I can't show that $s$ has a length greater than $f(n)*d$, which is the GapSVP problem.

> GapSVP and Lattices

In the work by Regev, cited in the question ([source](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/lwesurvey.pdf)), Regev covers basic definitions of lattices and lattice problems on page 8.  He defines the lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the set of all integer combinations of $n$ linearly independent vectors.  The set of $n$ linearly independent vectors is the basis of the lattice.

In LWE a number field $K$ is added to an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ which is used to introduce a cyclotomic polynomial.  These properties allow for the canonical embedding described by Regev in section 2.3.2.  One of the final requirements to establish the lattice geometry is to select a relevant norm.  Regev uses the norm of $l_\infty$.  This norm determines the expansion that occurs between elements under multiplication.

LWE uses a decision problem involving samples of LWE and a uniform distribution on $\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{q} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$ (Section 3, page 12).

> Applied Lattices

Returning to the short basis generator and vector pairs $(a_i, \quad b_i = \langle s, a_i \rangle + e_i)$ and $e_i \ll q$, I use $s$ to encrypt text which produces $e$.  Since $a_i$ is uniformly random, I take secret key $s$ as pair of $a$ and add it to the encrypted $e$.  I now have $b_i$ which I pair with $a_i$.  Now, any attempts to attack the scheme require *finding* $b_i$ compared to $a_i$, which is the SVP problem.  To separate $b_i$ from $a_i$ *after* finding $b_i$, is the GapSVP problem.  In the image below, the red vector represents the shortest non-zero vector, and the blue vectors are linearly independent of the red vectors and have basis $b_i$.  The red vector is private key $s$, and the blue vectors represent the public key of $m$ samples $(\mathbf{a}_i, b_i)$ from LWE distribution with secret $s$, mod $q$, and error parameter $\alpha$.  In the image you can easily see that neighboring points of the $s$ vector are approximate equidistant to the basis vector $b_i$, granting the security of private key $s$.  To place final context on this answer, you have to determine if $(b_1,b_2)$ are at most distance $d$ from $s$.

[image: SVP Problem]

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is: In what sense am I looking for a shortest non-zero vector in LWE? What do s and bi stand for with regards to lattices? Thanks!

Comment: (s) is the key for encrypted (e).  These two are (b), and you need to separate (a) from (b) to start any attack.  At the same time, (a) is also a generator paired with (s) which forms the vector.  So you first need to find (a), and then determine if it satisfies conditions for (b).

Comment: To see how this fits within the context of lattices, this video is a good overview.  The maths is nontrivial, but he uses graphs. Skip to 56:38.  https://youtu.be/P3I3kCJedIo

Comment: It might help to explain in the answer how solving LWE relates to solving a lattice problem, i.e. what lattice this corresponds to and how a solution corresponds to a shortest vector in this lattice.

Comment: @TMM I've updated the answer to reflect your concerns.

Comment: The update is not very clarifying. It also seems misguided at some places - there is a difference between (plain) LWE and ring-LWE. There's no need to introduces polynomial rings here. And you still have not explained what the lattice is (in terms of $a_i, b_i, s$) and why $s$ is a shortest vector of this lattice.

Comment: @TMM I have added further clarification.

Comment: The last part still seems confusing to me. LWE is not yet an encryption scheme, what do you mean by "use s to encrypt text which produces e"? And $b_i$ are just integers + error, why do you show it as vectors in the lattice ($\langle s, a_i \rangle$ denotes an inner product)?

Comment: My apologies.  I will remove my answer.  At this point it is too long in form, and becoming too time intensive.  I hope I've helped somewhat with your understanding of LWE.

Comment: If you'll kindly unaccept this answer, in light of the edits made, I will remove it.

Comment: @LQWE To address your comment, though, LWE is designed to be a crypto scheme.  The inner product is w.r.t. the integer product $\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{q} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$.  Since the comments are getting too long, and understanding my answer doesn't fully address your question I would like you to unaccept it as the answer so I can remove it.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't 100% get your answer. Thank you for your time though!

Comment: @LQWE I undeleted my answer.  I mistook your questions for TMM's, so I apologize.  I'm willing to answer questions you raise, but we should probably do so in a chat room to prevent too many comments on the answer.