# Relation between LPN and GAPSVP?

Tags: lattice-crypto

I have a question regarding the relationship between the (search) LPN problem and the GapSVP problem.

I have read a related problem that explains the main theorem in [Reg05](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1568318.1568324): the GapSVP problem can be reduced to a search LWE problem (especially, the modulus $p>2\sqrt{n}$).

> [What is the direct connection between LWE and GapSVP?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43889/what-is-the-direct-connection-between-lwe-and-gapsvp)

However, regarding the hardness of the search LPN problem, I noticed that some papers just introduce that the known fastest algorithm that solves the search LPN problem needs $2^{O(n/\log n)}$ time (i.e. [BKW algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0010022.pdf)).

I was wondering, whether there are some similar mature results about the relation between the search LPN problem and the GapSVP problem? Or, we believe the search LPN problem is hard, **SOLELY** because there is no known attack in polynomial time?

Many thanks.

Comment: There is no known reduction from GapSVP (or any other conjectured-hard worst-case lattice problem) to LPN, like there is for LWE. The conjectured hardness of LPN is mainly due to known algorithms for it being so inefficient.